# How do I extract and sort image attachment from emails?

Tags: linux, email, images, fetchmail, procmail

Here is what I was thinking of:

I want to create a Raspberry Pi Picture-frame (DPF) for my grandma, but with basic email support. Emails can be sent by six family members and will be received daily by fetchmail/procmail. This already works!

In `/home/pi/Mail/` I now have three files (one for each email including attachments):

- `msg.nTIB`
- `msg.pTIB`
- `msg.oTIB`

What I want to do now is extract SENDER, SUBJECT(, TEXT) and ATTACHMENT from each file, to rename the attachment-image and add the text with imagemagick (not yet included).

```
for file in msg.*; do
    export SENDER=`tee $file | formail -zxFrom: -zxReply-To:|cut -fs- -d'<'|cut -f1 -d'>'`
    SUBJECT = `/bin/cat $file | formail -zxSubject:`

    if grep -qxis $SENDER /home/pi/Mail/.markus; then
        SENDER2=Markus
    fi
    if grep -qxis $SENDER /home/pi/Mail/.someone; then
        SENDER2=Someone
    fi

    /bin/mkdir -p /home/pi/Mail/$SENDER2 >/dev/null 
    munpack -C /home/pi/Mail/$SENDER2 $file
    /bin/cat $file
    /bin/rm $file
done
```

The `grep` and `munpack` part works fine, but the extraction of SENDER and SUBJECT does not work when I run the sh-file. It just looks like it froze. I can only cancel it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>!

I don't know why, when I include line 2 and 3 in my `.procmailrc` it does work without problems.

I mean that this is a somehow basic task and no wizardry, but I couldn't find anything helpful with google `:/`

Any help is appreciated! Maybe you have got another solution. I'm totally not an expert in Linux, so maybe keep it a bit simple `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the `cat` and the `tee` are [useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat); the `tee` doubly so, and the reason for (what you perceive as) the script freezing.  It requires a file name argument, as the file to copy its input to, and a stream of text or data on standard input, which of course it's not receiving, so it sits there.

Additionally, [you should generally quote your variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable).

The `SENDER` extraction is kind of problematic.  Do you really want the variable to contain two strings?  Usually, you could simply do `formail -rtzxTo: <"$file"` and obtain a sane result.  (The `-t` option has some obscure semantics but for this sort of purpose, it probably does the right thing.)  That also does away with the pesky `cut`s to obtain just the email terminus (because `formail` in reply generation mode already does that for you).

Finally, `sh` syntax does not allow for whitespace around the equals sign in assignments.

```
for file in msg.*; do
    SENDER=$(formail -zxFrom: -zxReply-To: <"$file" |
        cut -fs- -d'<'|cut -f1 -d'>')
    SUBJECT=$(formail -zxSubject: <"$file")

    if grep -qxis "$SENDER" /home/pi/Mail/.markus; then
        SENDER2=Markus
    elif grep -qxis "$SENDER" /home/pi/Mail/.someone; then
        SENDER2=Someone
    fi

    mkdir -p /home/pi/Mail/"$SENDER2"
    munpack -C /home/pi/Mail/"$SENDER2" "$file"
    cat "$file"
    rm "$file"
done
```

I also removed the full paths from command names (you should simply make sure your `PATH` is sane instead) and switched from `` `obsolescent` `` process substitution syntax to `$(modern)`.  `mkdir -p` runs quietly, so I removed the output redirection from that.

The complex `grep` could be replaced with a simple mapping, something like this:

```
SENDER2=$(awk -v who="$SENDER" '
    $1 == who { print $2; x=1 } END { exit 1-x }' <<'________HERE'
        msmith@dmel.example.com    Markus
        someone@there.example.net  Someone
________HERE
```

This makes assumptions about what you have in the files you are currently grepping from, but you should get the idea.  This still doesn't solve how to set `SENDER2` if you don't have the sender on file; but perhaps the script should simply reject those files altogether for security reasons?

Comment: I'm sorry for my late answer, the above script worked very fine! However, the script below, which is a very nice solution does not work properly, i think there is something missing, but i couldn't fix it. And yes, if the Sender is unknown, email should be rejected. I don't want my grandma to receive spam or d*** pics ;)

Comment: Sorry about the trouble with the second script. Without more diagnostics, there's not much I can do, though. Perhaps you should post a new question with some diagnostics etc? Probably a good idea to include a link back to this question.